# AppCode IDE can not detect en localization keywords

Tags: ios, localization, appcode

Recently I used JetBrains AppCode IDE for developing my iOS application. It is cool but I have a problem with it.

I use below code for using a localized string:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"LI_HELP_SELECTINSURANCE_TITLE", LIApplicationLanguage(), nil)
```

but in all lines that I used above code its show below warning:

> en localization doesn't contains keyword for 'The Key Name'

It is while I have the key in my `en.strings` file. It is very good that I know that some keywords is not defined in some `.strings` file but when it warns for all files I can not detect the correct warns.

Does someone know how can we fix this problem?

Comment: This problem should be already fixed in the latest AppCode version. Please, try downloading AppCode 2016.1.2 from here https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/download/